# Customizing a React Bootstrap component, what does this notation mean?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm using `react-bootstrap` in my project and I want to customise a component, the official docs give an example of how to do this:

```
<>
  <style type="text/css">
    {`
    .btn-flat {
      background-color: purple;
      color: white;
    }

    .btn-xxl {
      padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    `}
  </style>

  <Button variant="flat" size="xxl">
    flat button
  </Button>
</>
```

I don't understand this notation. Is it defined in the `CSS` file or the component file? What does `<>` mean and why is there `<style type="text/css">`? Any pointers on this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`<></>` just allow you to wrap your returned value without adding a DOM node (= `React.Fragment` i think if you're familiar with this). For example :

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>A child</div>
      <div>Another child</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

About the style here, its made inside the return (it's wrapped in `<></>`) but in your project, you should separate it in a css file. They just did this to show you the available classes for you to customize the component (You can see it if you inspect the button).

Answer (score 0):

The [`<>`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html) is a shorthand for [`<React.Fragment>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) as you might know React component require a wrapping HTML tag element for the content, this lead sometime to more HTML tags that can be avoided in normal HTML, here where `<React.Fragment>` comes in hand to reduce the HTML added and avoiding add wrapping HTML element, also the style is one of the ways to style React, check this [repo](https://github.com/MicheleBertoli/css-in-js), I believe it to be  [styled-jsx](https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx) library.